# How to exclude certain fields from the selection using Drizzle ORM?

Tags: javascript, typescript, database, orm, drizzle

I’m using Drizzle ORM in my TypeScript project to work with a database, and I have a model representing user data that includes sensitive information like passwords. I want to exclude the ‘password’ field by default in all SELECT statements for security reasons.

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way to omit fields is with the `getTableColumns()` helper.

```
import { getTableColumns } from 'drizzle-orm';

const { password, ...nonPwCols } = getTableColumns(yourTable);
const result = await select(nonPwCols).from(yourTable);
```

See: [Relevant part of the docs](https://orm.drizzle.team/docs/goodies#get-typed-table-columns).